# Syntax error in route.rb Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

Just started learning Ruby on Rails and I have alot of issues setting up the project route in config/route.rb.

The main issue is, when I try making a Default route, it just won´t work.

When I make SOME commands in the Terminal, I get a Warning like this:
Warning: Running `gem pristine --all` to regenerate your installed gemspecs (and deleting then reinstalling your bundle if you use bundle --path) will improve the startup performance of Spring.

**This is the code in my routes.rb now:**

```
Rails::application.routes.draw do
  :get 'demo/index' 
  match ":controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))" , 
  :via => :get
```

**This is the error message I get when trying to open up in "localhost":**

> SyntaxError
> /Users/cathrinjanoy/Sites/simple_cms/config/routes.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_end :get 'demo/index' ^
>
> Extracted source (around line #3):
>
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
> 6
>
>
>
>
> Rails::application.routes.draw do
>
>   :get 'demo/index' 
>
>   match ":controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))" , 
>   :via => :get
>
> Rails.root: /Users/cathrinjanoy/Sites/simple_cms
>
>
>
> config/routes.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_end
>
> This error occurred while loading the following files:
>    /Users/cathrinjanoy/Sites/simple_cms/config/routes.rb

Can anyone help? I am so new to this but have been sitting for hours to try and get the routes.rb working and now I felt like asking for help!

Answer (score 3):

Intstead of

```
:get 'demo/index'
```

you should have

```
get 'demo/index'
```

Comment: Thank you! It actually solved the problem! Although I have no idea why the Simple route worked before but not the default route. For a while none of them worked but now both are running!